# trying to go from generic list via webapi and bind with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I am having a problem trying to bind my webapi data with knockoutjs. The json data comes back fine I believe but I don't know how to get it into the view model so knockout can use it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: Code"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function AppViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.seats = [];

            /*
            [
                { Code: 1, Name: "red" },
                { Code: 2, Name: "blue" }
            ];
            */

            $.get("/api/Test/Get", null, function (data) {
                //callback
                self.seats = data;
            },'json');

        }

        ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Server-side**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public List<UserSettings> Get()
        {
            List<UserSettings> list = new List<UserSettings>();
            UserSettings userSetting  = new UserSettings() { Code = 1, Name = "Name 01" };
            list.Add(userSetting);
            return list;
        }
    }

    public class UserSettings
    {
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `seats` to be an observableArray. Then, neatly, populating it just means making it the success function for your `get`:

```
  $.get("/api/Test/Get", null, self.seats, 'json');
```

The example below fakes the `get` with a timeout so you can see the populating happen.

```js
function AppViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.seats = ko.observableArray();

  /*
  $.get("/api/Test/Get", null, self.seats, 'json');
  */
  setTimeout(function() {
    self.seats(
      [{
        Code: 1,
        Name: "red"
      }, {
        Code: 2,
        Name: "blue"
      }]);
  }, 800);

}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: Code"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: is there a way to show the return data in an anonymous function for callback? I thought it would look like this $.get('/api/blah',null, function(data) { self.seats = data;}, 'json' but apparently not.

Comment: Sure, you can call whatever function you want. It's just that observables are getter/setters, so assigning them a value is a function invocation with the new value as an argument.